# spring: @bean CommandlineRunner. How it returns an object of type CommandlineRunner

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have seen in many places

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository repo) {
        return (args) -> {
        };
    }

}
```

how does

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository repo) {
    return (args) -> {
    };
}
```

return an object of type `CommandLineRunner`

it return a function

```
(args) -> {
        };
```

I am not able to understand the syntax also.

Can someone help me to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CommandLineRunner** is an interface used to indicate that a bean should run when it is contained within a SpringApplication. A Spring Boot application can have multiple beans implementing **CommandLineRunner**. These can be ordered with `@Order`.

It has one abstract method :

```
    void run(String... args) throws Exception
```

Consider below example:

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCommandLineRunner.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Loading data..." + args.toString());

    }
}
```

Since **CommandLineRunner** contains only only abstract method which return nothing so it automatically becomes the functional interface i.e. we can write lambda expression for it.

Above class can be written as :

```
(args) -> { 
    logger.info("Loading data..." + args.toString()) 
};
```

---

Coming to Your example :

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(String... args) {
    return (args) -> {
    };
}
```

You are expecting to register a bean in Spring Container which implements **CommandLineRunner** interface so it can converted to lambda expression.

```
(args) -> {};
```

---

Hope this would clarify it enough.

Answer (score 1):

you should check functional interfaces of Java,

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/

In syntheses,

A **functional interface** is a Java interface with only one abstract method (i.e., a method which has no instructions, only a name).

Functional interfaces are used together with lambda functions.

Suppose we have a functional interface

```
public interface JustAFunctionalInterface {
      void execute() {};
}
```

Notice we have only an abstract method, which does not do anything (no instructions).

This functional interface can be implemented like in your code above:

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            JustAFunctionalInterface variable = justAFunctionalInterface();
            variable.execute() // This will print "Hi"
      };

      public static JustAFunctionalInterface justAFunctionalInterface() {
          return (args) -> {System.out.println('Hi')} 
      }; // This chunk of code says that this method will return an interface of type 
         // JustAFunctionalInterface already implemented, where the abstract method "execute" is assigned the lambda function returned in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CommandLineRunner is a functional interface with one method that return void.

That is why when you write:  {  }; everything is OK.